# Unable to send mysql queries through python and tkinter

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I wanted to make a program which takes in stock name, stock unit price, total stocks bought using tkinter interface and updating a mysql database with the data:

```
import mysql.connector as mc
from tkinter import*
import time
from datetime import date

mycon=mc.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="1234",database="stock_manager")
cursor=mycon.cursor()

global date
date=date.today()

global stock_name
global stock_unit_price
global stocks_bought


def add():
    global stock_unit_price_entry
    global stocks_bought_entry
    global stock_name_entry
    global stock_name
    global stock_unit_price
    global stocks_bought
    stock_name_label=Label(root,text="Enter Stock Name")
    stock_name_entry=Entry(root,width=50)

    stock_unit_price_label=Label(root,text="Enter unit price of stock")
    stock_unit_price_entry=Entry(root,width=50)
    stock_unit_price_entry.insert(0,"0.00")

    stocks_bought_label=Label(root,text="Enter number of stocks bought: ")
    stocks_bought_entry=Entry(root,width=50)
    stocks_bought_entry.insert(0,"0")


    stock_name_label.grid(row=2,column=0)
    stock_name_entry.grid(row=3,column=0)
    stock_unit_price_label.grid(row=4,column=0)
    stock_unit_price_entry.grid(row=5,column=0)
    stocks_bought_label.grid(row=6,column=0)
    stocks_bought_entry.grid(row=7,column=0)

    submit_stock_button=Button(root,text="Submit",command=submit)
    submit_stock_button.grid(row=8,column=1)

def submit():
    global stock_name_entry
    global stock_unit_price_entry
    global stocks_bought_entry
    global stock_name
    global date
    global stock_unit_price
    global stocks_bought

    stock_unit_price=float(stock_unit_price_entry.get())
    stocks_bought=int(stocks_bought_entry.get())
    stock_name=stock_name_entry.get()

    total_investment=(stock_unit_price)*(stocks_bought)

    todo="insert into all_stocks values('%s',%s,%s,%s,'%s')"%(stock_name,stock_unit_price,stocks_bought,total_investment,date)
    print(todo)
    cursor.execute(todo)
    submitted_label=Label(root,text="Submitted!")
    submitted_label.grid(row=9,column=1)



root=Tk()
title_label=Label(root,text="All Investments")
add_stock_button=Button(root,text="Add Stock",command=add)
title_label.grid(row=0,column=1)
add_stock_button.grid(row=1,column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

in the above code, "todo" is the query that is going to be passed. I had printed the todo statement to check if the query is getting all the information correct. The input is as follows:
[input screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bP4aV.jpg)

The print(todo) output is as follows:
[todo output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIFUp.jpg)

The Mysql Table where the query is supposed to insert the values:
[mysql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKTbz.jpg)

And here lies the problem. The todo query is perfect. But it is not adding the row into the table. As you can see, the stock with the name "Future Generali" is already present. Our stock is "HDFC Bank" which has clearly not added.

Can someone help me with this. Is my code going somewhere wrong or does cursor not perform queries involving inserting values in tables. If so, what is the solution. Pls help me.

Comment: You have to commit your changes, try saying `cursor.execute('commit')` after saying `cursor.execute(todo)`

Comment: `todo="insert into all_stocks values('%s',%s,%s,%s,'%s')"%(stock_name,stock_unit_price,stocks_bought,total_investment,date)` .Your `stock_unit_price` and `stocks_bought` are of datatype `double` . Please dont insert it as  `%s%s` . Please check your `database column` datatype and match with it with datatype that you are inserting

Comment: @Karthik So how to change the datatype from double to that of the column?

Comment: @CoolCloud Ill try that, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @G Anand Iyengar Please check for what type of column you created for `stock_unit_price and stocks_bought` in your database.  **Mainly check the datatype of your column `date` .As i feel it might be of datatype `datetime` but here it is a string**

Comment: To understand your table better, you can run a sql command on your mysql command line,like `DESCRIBE all_stocks`, there you can identify your datatype used by each column